# Unable to create donate button when using Paypal business account

Tags: paypal

I am using a Paypal business account but am unable to create a Donate button. Inside the "Create a Paypal Payment Button" page, Paypal shows four options in the drop down list, but there is no option to create a Donation button. Does any one have an idea as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal donation buttons are not supported for all the countries .
Supported countries include FR,IT,BR,CA,AU,GB,US etc